# Explode a column with a List of Jsons with Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, etl

I was trying to explode a column called phones like the following schema and content:

```
(customer_external_id,StringType
phones,StringType)

customer_id    phones
x8x46x5        [{"phone" : "(xx) 35xx4x80"},{"phone" : "(xx) xxxx46605"}]
xx44xx5        [{"phone" : "(xx) xxx3x8443"}]
4xxxxx5        [{"phone" : "(xx) x6xx083x3"},{"areaCode" : "xx"},{"phone" : "(xx) 3xxx83x3"}]
xx6564x        [{"phone" : "(x3) x88xx344x"}]
xx8x4x0        [{"phone" : "(xx) x83x5x8xx"}]
xx0434x        [{"phone" : "(0x) 3x6x4080"},{"areaCode" : "xx"}]
x465x40        [{"phone" : "(6x) x6x445xx"}]
x0684x8        [{"phone" : "(xx) x8x88x4x4"},{"phone" : "(xx) x8x88x4x4"}]
x84x850        [{"phone" : "(xx) 55x56xx4"}]
x0604xx        [{"phone" : "(xx) x8x4xxx68"}]
4x6xxx0        [{"phone" : "(xx) x588x43xx"},{"phone" : "(xx) 5x6465xx"},{"phone" : "(xx) x835xxxx8"},{"phone" : "(xx) x5x6465xx"}]
x6x000x        [{"phone" : "(xx) xxx044xx4"}]
5x65533        [{"phone" : "(xx) xx686x0xx"}]
x3668xx        [{"phone" : "(5x) 33x8x3x4"},{"phone" : "(5x) 8040x8x6"}]
```

So I tried to run this code and got the subsequential error:

```
df.select('customer_external_id', explode(df.phones))

AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'explode(`phones`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not StringType;;
'Project [customer_external_id#293, explode(phones#296) AS List()]\n+- Relation[order_id#292,customer_external_id#293,name#294,email#295,phones#296,phones_version#297,classification#298,locale#299] parquet\n"
```

And by this error I found out my column was a StringType so I ran this  code to remove brackets and convert to json:

```
phones = df.select('customer_external_id', 'phones').rdd\
    .map(lambda x: str(x).replace('[','')\
                       .replace(']','')\
                       .replace('},{', ','))\
    .map(lambda x: json.loads(x).get('phone')\
    .map(lambda x: Row(x))\
    .toDF(df.select('customer_external_id','phones').schema)
phones.show()

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 38.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 38.0 (TID 2740, 10.112.80.248, executor 8): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Apparently I can't cast to Json and I can't explode the column. So how could I properly deal with this kind of data to get this output:

```
    +-----------+--------+--------------+
    |customer_id|areaCode|phone         |
    +-----------+--------+--------------+
    |x8x46x5    |null    |(xx) 35xx4x80 |
    |x8x46x5    |null    |(xx) xxxx46605|
    |xx44xx5    |null    |(xx) xxx3x8443|
    |4xxxxx5    |null    |(xx) x6xx083x3|
    |4xxxxx5    |xx      |null          |
    |4xxxxx5    |null    |(xx) 3xxx83x3 |
    |xx6564x    |null    |(x3) x88xx344x|
    |xx8x4x0    |null    |(xx) x83x5x8xx|
    |xx0434x    |null    |(0x) 3x6x4080 |
    |xx0434x    |xx      |null          |
    |x465x40    |null    |(6x) x6x445xx |
    |x0684x8    |null    |(xx) x8x88x4x4|
    |x0684x8    |null    |(xx) x8x88x4x4|
    |x84x850    |null    |(xx) 55x56xx4 |
    |x0604xx    |null    |(xx) x8x4xxx68|
    |4x6xxx0    |null    |(xx) x588x43xx|
    |4x6xxx0    |null    |(xx) 5x6465xx |
    |4x6xxx0    |null    |(xx) x835xxxx8|
    |4x6xxx0    |null    |(xx) x5x6465xx|
    |x6x000x    |null    |(xx) xxx044xx4|
    |5x65533    |null    |(xx) xx686x0xx|
    |x3668xx    |null    |(5x) 33x8x3x4 |
    |x3668xx    |null    |(5x) 8040x8x6 |
    +-----------+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: Why not create a schema for the dataset and then pass it while reading the file?

Comment: Why are you doing the `string.replace()` steps? Can't you just do `json.loads()`? That should return a `list` of `dicts` - then you should be able to call `flatMap()`. Also, can you show what your desired output should look like?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944084/3251351 This sticks to pure DataFrame API and avoids serialization/deserialization of the records between JVM and Python and uses built-in, optimized functions for handling JSON.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want to do is use the `from_json` method to convert the string into an array and then explode:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

phone_schema = ArrayType(StructType([StructField("phone", StringType())]))

converted = inputDF\
  .withColumn("areaCode", get_json_object("phones", "$[*].areaCode"))\
  .withColumn("phones", explode(from_json("phones", phone_schema)))\
  .withColumn("phone", col("phones.phone"))\
  .drop("phones")\
  .filter(~isnull("phone"))

converted.show()
```

Comment: This is great- I have been searching for a way to do `flatMap()` with Spark- I think this is the way!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to directly call `json.loads()` without using `replace()` as  you have shown.

1. Map the `string` to `ArrayType(MapType())` using `json.loads()`.
2. Call `flatMap()` to create a new `Row()` for each element of the array.
3. Map these rows to the desired output.

Take a look at the following example:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from pyspark.sql import Row
import json
import pandas as pd

# mock up some sample data
data = StringIO("""customer_id\tphones
x8x46x5\t[{"phone" : "(xx) 35xx4x80"},{"phone" : "(xx) xxxx46605"}]
xx44xx5\t[{"phone" : "(xx) xxx3x8443"}]
4xxxxx5\t[{"phone" : "(xx) x6xx083x3"},{"areaCode" : "xx"},{"phone" : "(xx) 3xxx83x3"}]
xx6564x\t[{"phone" : "(x3) x88xx344x"}]
xx8x4x0\t[{"phone" : "(xx) x83x5x8xx"}]
xx0434x\t[{"phone" : "(0x) 3x6x4080"},{"areaCode" : "xx"}]
x465x40\t[{"phone" : "(6x) x6x445xx"}]
x0684x8\t[{"phone" : "(xx) x8x88x4x4"},{"phone" : "(xx) x8x88x4x4"}]
x84x850\t[{"phone" : "(xx) 55x56xx4"}]
x0604xx\t[{"phone" : "(xx) x8x4xxx68"}]
4x6xxx0\t[{"phone" : "(xx) x588x43xx"},{"phone" : "(xx) 5x6465xx"},{"phone" : "(xx) x835xxxx8"},{"phone" : "(xx) x5x6465xx"}]
x6x000x\t[{"phone" : "(xx) xxx044xx4"}]
5x65533\t[{"phone" : "(xx) xx686x0xx"}]
x3668xx\t[{"phone" : "(5x) 33x8x3x4"},{"phone" : "(5x) 8040x8x6"}]""")

pandas_df =  pd.read_csv(data, sep="\t")
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(pandas_df)  # convert pandas to spark df

# run the steps outlined above
df.rdd\
    .map(lambda x: Row(customer_id=x['customer_id'], phones=json.loads(x['phones'])))\
    .flatMap(lambda x: [Row(customer_id=x['customer_id'], phone=phone) for phone in x['phones']])\
    .map(lambda x: Row(customer_id=x['customer_id'], phone=x['phone'].get('phone'), areaCode=x['phone'].get('areaCode')))\
    .toDF()\
    .select('customer_id', 'areaCode', 'phone')\
    .show(truncate=False, n=100)
```

The output:

```
+-----------+--------+--------------+
|customer_id|areaCode|phone         |
+-----------+--------+--------------+
|x8x46x5    |null    |(xx) 35xx4x80 |
|x8x46x5    |null    |(xx) xxxx46605|
|xx44xx5    |null    |(xx) xxx3x8443|
|4xxxxx5    |null    |(xx) x6xx083x3|
|4xxxxx5    |xx      |null          |
|4xxxxx5    |null    |(xx) 3xxx83x3 |
|xx6564x    |null    |(x3) x88xx344x|
|xx8x4x0    |null    |(xx) x83x5x8xx|
|xx0434x    |null    |(0x) 3x6x4080 |
|xx0434x    |xx      |null          |
|x465x40    |null    |(6x) x6x445xx |
|x0684x8    |null    |(xx) x8x88x4x4|
|x0684x8    |null    |(xx) x8x88x4x4|
|x84x850    |null    |(xx) 55x56xx4 |
|x0604xx    |null    |(xx) x8x4xxx68|
|4x6xxx0    |null    |(xx) x588x43xx|
|4x6xxx0    |null    |(xx) 5x6465xx |
|4x6xxx0    |null    |(xx) x835xxxx8|
|4x6xxx0    |null    |(xx) x5x6465xx|
|x6x000x    |null    |(xx) xxx044xx4|
|5x65533    |null    |(xx) xx686x0xx|
|x3668xx    |null    |(5x) 33x8x3x4 |
|x3668xx    |null    |(5x) 8040x8x6 |
+-----------+--------+--------------+
```

I'm not sure if this is the output you were hoping for, but this should help you get there.