# PySpark error loading data (JSON array) into a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load a JSON file into a dataframe in PySpark (Notebook).
**value** column is an array (multiple records), so need output data to look like below.
The problem is value column is enclosed in double quotes and PySpark is treating it as a string (instead of array), and can't explode this to multiple records. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!!

**Error:** AnalysisException: cannot resolve explode(Value) due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not string;

| name | value | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| testcase_1234 | To do | 1 |
| testcase_1234 | In Review | 2 |
| testcase_5678 | To do | 1 |
| testcase_5678 | In Review | 2 |

```
Sample JSON Input
{
    "name": "testcase_1234",
    "value": "[{\"value\":\"To do\",\"id\":\"1\"},{\"value\":\"In Review\",\"id\":\"2\"}]"
},
{
    "name": "testcase_5678",
    "value": "[{\"value\":\"To do\",\"id\":\"1\"},{\"value\":\"In Review\",\"id\":\"2\"}]"
}

PySpark Code:

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

rawDF = spark.read.json([f"abfss://{pADLSContainer}@{pADLSGen2}.dfs.core.windows.net/{pADLSDirectory}/{pFilePrefix}_1.json"], multiLine = "false")
rawDF.printSchema()
expDF = rawDF.select(
                col("name").alias("name"),
                col("value").alias("value"),
                explode("value").alias("ExpValue")
                ) 
expDF.show(n=2,vertical=True,truncate=150)

Output:
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)

AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'explode(`defaultValue`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not string;
```

Comment: You should define a schema and implement something similar mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942875/explode-a-column-with-a-list-of-jsons-with-pyspark)

Comment: This solution is exactly what I needed.
Thanks for the suggestion @AkhilJain !